# How can I have multiple connections through AFP?

Tags: time-machine, nas, afp

I have a Synology NAS and I always connect to it through AFP. I enter my login and password and I can access all the shares.

Recently, I have started to use TimeMachine and I created a user for it that can only access the backup partition.

Now, when the computer starts, TimeMachine logs in and then any attemp I make at connecting to the AFP service uses the credentials of the current connection (the TimeMachine ones) and I can't access the other partitions.

How can I have two separate logins going on at the same time?